# Partial Fibonacci Sum, how to improve performance?

Tags: ruby, fibonacci

I need to improve the performance of this algorithm. I believe the answer lies in the application of the pisano period.

This algorithm must return the last digit of the sum of fib numbers from f(m) to f(n).

Here is what I have so far:

```
def fib(n)
    a = []
    a << 0 << 1
    (n+1).times do |i|
        a << a[-1] + a[-2]
    end
     a[n]
end


def fib_partial_sum(m, n)
    if n == m
        fib(m) % 10
    else
        m = fib(m + 1) - 1
        n = fib(n + 2) - 1
        (n - m) % 10
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  m, n = gets.split().map(&:to_i)
  puts "#{fib_partial_sum(m, n)}"
end
```

The last digit of any fib num repeats every 60 numbers. Therefore, we can do this,  n, m = n % 60, m % 60. An improvement, but not quite there yet, fails on input 567717153638 567717153638):

```
def fib(n)
    a = []
    a << 0 << 1
    (n+1).times do |i|
        a << a[-1] + a[-2]
    end
     a[n]
end

def fib_partial_sum(m, n)
    if n == m
        fib(m)
    else
        m = m % 60
        n = n % 60

        m = fib(m + 1) - 1
        n = fib(n + 2) - 1
        (n - m) % 10
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  m, n = gets.split().map(&:to_i)
  puts "#{fib_partial_sum(m, n)}"
end
```

Comment: Should this be on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?  Unless it is code that is not working.  The title suggests it is, but questioning performance.

Comment: Do you have a limit on memory? Are you allowed to employ memoization techniques? Only looking at your code, you could optimize the calls to `fib` on `fib_partial_sum`: there is some overlap of computation there.

Comment: Maybe, I've never used code review....I'll look into it

Comment: Yes there is a memory limit - it is presently failing on a memory usage limit. It also takes forever with large inputs.

Comment: Well, you are basically computing `fib` for 1 through `m` then from 1 through `n`. You could implement (maybe with an inline iteration) from 1 through `m` then from `m` through `n`.

Comment: By the way, do you have a reason for using an array on `fib`? Your function basically returns a number; you could easily do the same using two temporary variables instead of an array (which has overhead of allocation/reallocation and garbage collection and also a much larger memory footprint).

Comment: re your first method, why not write `a = [0,1]` instead and the parameter of your times block is redundant. Also this method doesn't return the correct number in the sequence. `n=3` should return 1 but returns 2. These points do not really help answer your question but will help refactor your code.

Comment: The final digits of Fibonacci numbers repeat every sixty numbers, so you can replace n and m with n % 60 and m % 60. (You could really just use an array of the final digit sequence, but you're probably trying to learn algorithm techniques, so that might not be what you're looking for.)

Comment: @sagarpandya82, the assignment is using base 0...so f(2) is 2. I.E [0,1,1,2]

Comment: @nloveladyallen, this is exactly what I am trying to implement. Everything else runs to slow. I'll try your suggestion. Can I just add the array of final digit sequence together??

Comment: @nloveladyallen I added an updated using your suggestion, it was definitely an improvement, but not quite there yet. I need to figure out how to add together the remainders without actually storing the whole fibonacci number...I think

Comment: @matthewalexander It's failing on that input because you only changed the `else` in `fib_partial_sum` and in this case n = m. Change the `if` body to `fib(m % 60)` and it should work.

Comment: @nloveladyallen, YES!! Thanks so much, spent the better part of today working on this.

Comment: @nloveladyallen, if `m = 59` and `n = 60`, you suggest one can consider the range from `59` to `0`. What does that mean?

Comment: Please don't add "edit" or "update" tags in your text because they're just visual noise. Instead, incorporate the change as if it'd been in place when you initially created the question. We can tell what's been changed if we want to know. Also, adding a "working solution" doesn't really help; By selecting the appropriate answer you award that user. See "[How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)". SO isn't a discussion board, it's an online reference, so we do things differently.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That is correct. All that matters is the last digit of the number. f(60) is 1548008755920 and f(0) is 0, so they are the same for the purposes of this question.

Comment: @theTinMan, thanks I'll remember for future posts. In this case, no one posted a working answer - I pieced it together from comments. I guess I should have posted the answer by clicking 'Answer your question'?

Comment: I suggest you clean up your question, as many members may view it in future. Questions are not meant to changed, except for clarification. If you wish to offer a solution, make it an answer (which you may choose to accept with ✅). If you revise your answer, remove the earlier one. I suggest your question end with "Any insight is greatly appreciated." (without "UPDATE: " preceding "This algorithm...") and your answer be the text following "UPDATE, WORKING SOLUTION! Big thanks..." You can acknowledge contributions in the question or in a comment. I prefer the latter, to keep answers clean.

Comment: `"Any insight is greatly appreciated."` is also not desirable. While it's nice to express appreciation for help, SO, being a reference book and not a discussion board, has a bit more formal stance. Think of it as a text book or cookbook and write accordingly. Some familiarity and friendliness is welcome but signatures, greetings and thanks are not and get edited out.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips guys - I'll make the suggested amendments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice solution to the problem, it passes all time and memory constraints. 
This way you never have to calculate a fib num greater that f(60). It can handle very large inputs efficiently.

```
def fib(n)
    a, b = 0, 1
    (n-1).times do
        a, b = b, (a + b) % 10
    end
    b
end

def fib_partial_sum(m, n)
    if n == m
        fib(m % 60)
    else
        m = m % 60
        n = n % 60

        m = fib(m + 1) - 1
        n = fib(n + 2) - 1

        (n - m) % 10
    end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
    m, n = gets.split().map(&:to_i)
    puts "#{fib_partial_sum(m, n)}"
end
```

(Max time used: 0.05/5.00, max memory used: 8699904/536870912.)

Answer (score 0):

The following requires only a single pass of the numbers between zero and at most `[n,m+60].min`, where `m..n` is the range of interest, and has a minimal memory requirement. It makes use of @nloveladyallen's observation that the last digit of Fibonacci numbers has a periodicity of 60.

**Code**

```
def fib_last(m,n)
  n -= 60*((n-m)/60)   
  fib_sum(m,n) % 10
end

def fib_sum(m,n)
  return nil if m < 0 || m > n
  return n if n < 2
  next_to_last, last = fib(m-1)
  (m..n).reduce(0) do |tot,_|
    current = next_to_last + last
    next_to_last = last
    last = current
    tot + current
  end
end

def fib(m)
  next_to_last, last = -1, 1
  0.upto(m).each do |n|
    current = next_to_last + last
    next_to_last, last = last, current
  end
  [next_to_last, last]
end
```

**Example**

```
m, n = 6, 12
(n+1).times { |i| puts "#{i}: #{fib(i)}" }
0:  [0,    0]
1:  [0,    1]
2:  [1,    1]
3:  [1,    2]
4:  [2,    3]
5:  [3,    5]
6:  [5,    8]
7:  [8,   13]
8:  [13,  21]
9:  [21,  34]
10: [34,  55]
11: [55,  89]
12: [89, 144]

fib_last(6,12) #=> 4 (fib_sum(6,12) #=> 8 + 13 + 21 + 34 + 55 + 89 + 144 = 364)
fib_last(1,2)  #=> 2 (fib_sum(1,2)  #=> 1 + 1 = 2)
fib_last(1,3)  #=> 4 (fib_sum(1,3)  #=> 1 + 1 + 2 = 4) 
fib_last(1,4)  #=> 7 (fib_sum(1,4)  #=> 1 + 1 + 2 + 3 = 7)
fib_last(2,3)  #=> 3 (fib_sum(2,3)  #=> 1 + 2 = 3)
```

Comment: fails on input 1, 2

Comment: fails on input 1, 3

Comment: Hi Cary - thanks so much for the effort, please see my latest update for the solution I was after. I had strict time and memory constraints to work with.

Comment: I've modified my code to incorporate @nloveladyallen's observation concerning the periodicity of the last digit of Fibonacci numbers.